# Should I edit the whole question or just post an update, to address the comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Admittedly, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21319300/1768303) composed in a bad way, initially at least. As some people were asking for clarifications, I was posting updates one by one, to address each comment, marking each update with **[UPDATE]** outline.

I usually do so, to make sure the comments made by others still remain valid, once the question has been edited. This time though, someone suggested that instead of posting updates, I should consider editing the question as a whole, so I did just that.

Is it a good practice to adhere to?

Outside the context of that specific question, is it not a concern that some comments may simply loose sense, if the question has been edited the way it looks as an original unedited post? I don't think people often care to check the history of editions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions should avoid having a "sense of time", they are forever and should feel as if they were asked all at once in the best way possible. Make your question as good as it can be (don't invalidate existing answers however)

Comments on the other hand are transitory and will likely be deleted once you have made your edit. Never worry about invalidating them. You can even flag comments as "obsolete" after you have incorporated their suggestions and a moderator will delete them or you can @reply their author to say you've made the changes and the author will most likely delete them themselves.

Comment: It's almost a revelation to me, I wish I followed it from the beginning.

Comment: On: "*will likely be deleted once you have made your edit*"; well, most often no, actually. And I have flagged many obsolete comments for moderator deletion and they have been almost universally rejected, even though be unquestionably irrelevant after the post was changed. Of the hundreds of flags I've done, almost the only rejections I've had are those for obsolete comments, so I highly doubt I am misflagging in these cases.

Comment: And @reply to the author just adds one more obsolete comment, unless you remember to go back and remove your comment telling the other person to remove their comment.

Comment: @Software In all fairness those comments are useful beyond the possible deletion because they ping a user who was interested in the question that the question may now be answerable

Comment: @RichardTingle, OTOH, if the obsolete comment hasn't been deleted, it may turn users off the question, especially if the comment came from a high-profile user.

Comment: @Noseratio indeed,  best case scenario you want outdated comments gone from the question.  Second best is a comment saying the comment has been dealt with

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: In general, mods don't get involved unless the material in question is harmful in some way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'd like to chance to thank you for your original suggestion, I believe it was you :) Does the same guideline also apply to editing own answers?

Comment: @Noseratio: Yes, it does.  Basically, we're compiling information for future readers.  We don't put EDIT: in our answers for the same reasons that book authors don't put EDIT: in their books, except that we actually have an edit history.

Comment: @Robert: OK - then what's the point in flagging a comment as obsolete?? That feature should be removed if mods are ***not *** actually going to remove obsolete comments.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: To remove noise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think software monkey is asking with relation to "In general, mods don't get involved unless the material in question is harmful in some way. "

Comment: A good example are pre-migration comments ("This question belongs on Programmers.") These are useless once the question is migrated. But comments that provide context for a question and its past edits can still have value, even though they are technically obsolete.  The "big city" nature of Stack Overflow nearly demands that mods only focus on things that are genuine problems for the site and its participants.

Comment: @Robert: Ahh. Then I guess we'd have to agree to disagree; as far as I am concerned, once the edit has been done the comment that suggests or requests it is obsolete and should be removed (along with the "@JoeBlow: Thanks, did that, question/answer updated" comment from the OP).

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: The thing you have to remember about mods who go through a thousand flags a day is the question they ask of every flag: *is this content harming the site?*  If it is, it has a much greater chance of being acted on.  All other things being equal, casting a custom flag that *answers this question* is better than casting a canned flag.

Comment: @Robert the obsolete flag has always seemed bizarre to me. If all users used it (in my opinion) correctly it would crash the moderator system

Comment: Why can't the obsolete flag be changed to notify the owner of the comment??

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: Post a Feature Request and find out.  My guess is that users already get enough notifications, and comments (which are already second-class citizens anyway) are not worth the context-switch.

Comment: @Robert: Then the obsolete flag should be removed, since no mod worth their salt is going to conclude that an obsolete comment is "harming" the site, and (apparently) we presume that no user deems it worth the effort either.

Comment: Well, I already gave you an example of an obsolete comment that every mod would remove: pre-migration comments ("This question belongs on Programmers.")

Comment: @Robert: "*Post a Feature Request and find out*". Sorry, I've learned from experience that making a feature request is a waste of my time - it'll either be rejected or marked complete when it was in fact rejected. It's better to just let the SO programmers get on with it and make their own decisions, which is what they do anyway.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: To be fair, the "obsolete" flag makes more sense on the low-volume sites than it does on the Trilogy, although I do get my fair share of declined obsolete flags on Programmers.  As a mod, I only delete obsolete comments when it is clearly apparent that they are useless.

Comment: I can believe it being a lot of work to determine if some comments really are obsolete.  Especially without subject level knowledge